# Remainder and well ordering principle

Tags: number-theory

Why must the remainder $r$ be the smallest nonnegative integer of the form  $a-bn$ when applying the division algorithm to $a$ and $b$? In the proof of the division algorithm, we use the fact that the set of all nonnegative integers of the form $a-nb$ is nonempty and the well ordering principle to show that $r$ exists, but must $r$ be the least element of that set?

Comment: It doesn't have to be. One can choose whatever coset representative of $\mathbb Z/b\mathbb Z$ you want as appropriate for a given problem, but you should be consistent.

Comment: Because this way you have a unique choice (and the minimal one). Otherwise, why not simply choosing $n=0$ and the remainder to be $a$?

Comment: What I (and I think most mathematicians) mean by the division algorithm is, given $a$ and $b$, produce $n$ and $r$ such that $a=bn+r$ and $0\leq r<b$. The last part of the conclusion, $0\leq r<b$, would be violated if $r$ were not the smallest nonnegative number of the form $a-bn$.

Comment: @user5713492. ..and taking the smallest $\tau$ makes the algorithm run the fastest.